# 1 IntelliSense: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "bool" to "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>"

Tags: c++, string, validation

Hey im getting this error when trying to validate a string.  Basically i want the game to not continue until the user enters a valid name.   John, Mary etc.. and not a number 123434 etc...

Here is my code:

```
string input1 ="What is your name ?\n";
    string name = getString(input1);//The error is in the getString.

bool getString(string str)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
  {
   if (isdigit(str[i]))
      return false;
   }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 string name = getString(input1);//The error is in the getString.
```

You can't cast a bool to a string or convert a `bool` to `string`, there is no `implicit conversion`. Perhaps you really want to return a string. I'm not sure as you name your function `getString`, yet you return a `bool`.

Unless you have a list of names handy and compare the input against the database, file etc..  comparing the input can be difficult. 
What if the user enters **Dsjdksdksdksdskd**?

To help/answer your question:

```
if(isDigitInString(name))
{

}
```

Comment: I was given a little bit of help on SO with this Lewis.

Comment: No @Pendo826, maybe you want to name your function `isDigitInString()` or similar. Good luck anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

you trying to assign a bool value to a string hence an error. You should write something like this -

```
    if(getString(input1))
    {
       // code which continues the game
    } 
    else
    {
       // show some error message or ask for input again 
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the function rather than doing this ?